# VPN DNS Leak when using OpenVPN on WIndows 10 (December 2019) - Specifically with Private Internet Access

Tags: windows-10, openvpn

I understand there have been issues with DNS leaks with Windows 10 as of several years ago.  There was a plug-in developed: [ValdikSS/openvpn-fix-dns-leak-plugin](https://github.com/ValdikSS/openvpn-fix-dns-leak-plugin), but it was supposed incorporated into OpenVPN staring with v. 2.3.9.  I am currently on OpenVPN 2.4.8.  I have also added this to the client OpenVPN config file:

```
dhcp-option DNS 209.222.18.222
register-dns
block-outside-dns
```

I have reviewed:
[PIA forum](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/25316/is-it-possible-to-prevent-dns-leak-with-openvpn-client)

After about 10 rounds of email support with PIA, I have gotten no where.  Does anyone have any other thoughts or insights on how to prevent DNS leaks with PIA (Private Internet Access)?  I am not sure if this specific to PIA or just Windows 10 in general.

Comment: How do you know your DNS is leaking?

Comment: Last time I check (quite some time ago), `def1` could cause leak in some cases in Windows. See if `pull-filter ignore "redirect-gateway "` *and* `redirect-gateway` helps.

Comment: If I test through DNSLeak.com or DNSleaktest.com, they leak.

Comment: See if pull-filter ignore "redirect-gateway " and redirect-gateway ... It still Leaks :(

Comment: you can for dns leaks check here>>>>https://www.routersecurity.org/testdns.php

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this solved my problem in Windows 10:

In short, edit the local group Policy and turn off Smart Multi-Homed Name Resolution.

Note that the Group Policy Editor is only available in professional editions of Windows 10. Windows 10 Home users may want to check out Policy Plus or some other method that introduces policy editing to Home editions of Windows 10.

```
- Do the following to open the Group Policy Editor in Windows: Tap on the Windows-key on the keyboard, type gpedit.msc, and hit the Enter-key on the keyboard.
- Go to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > DNS Client > Turn off smart multi-homed name resolution.
- Set the policy to enabled, to disable the smart multi-homed name resolution feature of the system.
```

Original solution found here:

https://www.ghacks.net/2017/08/14/turn-off-smart-multi-homed-name-resolution-in-windows/

**Update** this solution only worked for a short time, so I found that it was necessary to adjust a few other settings in the group policy editor. make yours look like mine, and your problems with DNS will be over:
[Group Policy Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdZUV.png)

Comment: I ended up having a couple extra network adapters (L2TP, etc.) and they were probably causing the leak.  It resolved after deleting these old network adapters

Answer (score 0):

**Update: after a while, this answer stopped working and DNS request started leaking again. I tried enabling the 4 total policies outlined in the [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1513537/774265), but I had DNS leaks even with all 4 enabled.**

**TL;DR**

*Group Policy Editor is only available in Windows 10 Pro. Other users, see other answer on ways to access this feature.

1. Press Win+R and write **gpedit.msc**
2. Expand *Administrative templates*
3. Expand *Network*
4. Click *DNS client*
5. Double-click "Turn off smart multi-homed name resolution"
6. Select the option "**Enabled**"
7. Click "OK"
8. Double-click "Primary DNS suffix"
9. Select the option "**Enabled**"
10. Click "OK"

**Longer Explanation**

The screenshot provided by [user1125497](https://superuser.com/a/1513537/774265) in their answer shows four policies enabled, but you only need these two (two of the other ones in their [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdZUV.png) says in the description that they don't do anything if "Turn off smart multi-homed name resolution" is enabled)

Many places around the internet says to enable "Turn off smart multi-homed name resolution" if you're facing DNS leak issues, but this doesn't fully solve the issue (What this setting does is prevent Windows from ALWAYS sending DNS request to all available networks). Even with this enabled, it seems that Windows will still send DNS requests to other network adapters if there is a delay in getting a DNS response from the primary adapter (see [here](https://serverfault.com/a/84293)).

I'm not certain what enabling "Primary DNS suffix" does, but I can confirm that it, in combination with "Turn off smart multi-homed name resolution", **does** seem to prevent the DNS leaks.